# Set::combine Cakephp, creating multi dimensional array using single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array having multiple values for same values for array of same keys

eg.

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
                  'name' => "Bob",
                  'age'  => 20,
                  'marks'=> 50
               )
   [1] => Array(
                  'name' => "Ryan",
                  'age'  => 20,
                  'marks'=> 57
               )
   [2] => Array(
                  'name' => "Allen",
                  'age'  => 23,
                  'marks'=> 70
               )
   [3] => Array(
                  'name' => "Duke",
                  'age'  => 23,
                  'marks'=> 67
               )
   [4] => Array(
                  'name' => "Matt",
                  'age'  => 24,
                  'marks'=> 85
               )
)
```

I want to convert them to according to there age as following using Set::Combine in Cakephp.

```
Array(
   [20] => Array(
                 [0] => Array(
                             'name' => "Bob",
                             'age'  => 20,
                             'marks'=> 50
                             )
                 [1] => Array(
                             'name' => "Ryan",
                             'age'  => 20,
                             'marks'=> 57
                             )
                )
   [23] => Array(
                 [0] => Array(
                             'name' => "Allen",
                             'age'  => 23,
                             'marks'=> 70
                             )
                 [1] => Array(
                             'name' => "Duke",
                             'age'  => 23,
                             'marks'=> 67
                             )
                )
   [24] => Array(
                 [0] => Array(
                             'name' => "Matt",
                             'age'  => 24,
                             'marks'=> 85
                             )
                )

 )
```

I'm only able to get one content for a particular age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can obtain almost what you want using this (tested with CakePHP 3):

```
Hash::combine($array, '{n}.user', '{n}', '{n}.age') ;
```

You can then use `array_map`  and `array_values` to get exactly what you want:

```
array_map('array_values', Hash::combine($array, '{n}.name', '{n}', '{n}.age'))
```

**Do not forget** to add the following `use`  statement: `use \Cake\Utility\Hash ;`

**Edit:** It looks like you are using CakePHP 2, the above should work, you simply need to replace `Hash` by `Set`:

```
array_map('array_values', Set::combine($array, '{n}.name', '{n}', '{n}.age'))
```

Example:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => "Bob",
        'age'  => 20,
        'marks'=> 50
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => "Ryan",
        'age'  => 20,
        'marks'=> 57
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => "Allen",
        'age'  => 23,
        'marks'=> 70
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => "Duke",
        'age'  => 23,
        'marks'=> 67
    ),
    4 => array(
        'name' => "Matt",
        'age'  => 24,
        'marks'=> 85
    )
) ;
debug($array);
debug(\Cake\Utility\Hash::combine($array, '{n}.user', '{n}', '{n}.age'));
debug(array_map('array_values', \Cake\Utility\Hash::combine($array, '{n}.name', '{n}', '{n}.age')));
```

Output:

```
\src\Controller\PagesController.php (line 61) 

[
    (int) 0 => [
        'name' => 'Bob',
        'age' => (int) 20,
        'marks' => (int) 50
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'name' => 'Ryan',
        'age' => (int) 20,
        'marks' => (int) 57
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'name' => 'Allen',
        'age' => (int) 23,
        'marks' => (int) 70
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'name' => 'Duke',
        'age' => (int) 23,
        'marks' => (int) 67
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'name' => 'Matt',
        'age' => (int) 24,
        'marks' => (int) 85
    ]
]


\src\Controller\PagesController.php (line 62) 

[
    (int) 20 => [
        'Bob' => [
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'age' => (int) 20,
            'marks' => (int) 50
        ],
        'Ryan' => [
            'name' => 'Ryan',
            'age' => (int) 20,
            'marks' => (int) 57
        ]
    ],
    (int) 23 => [
        'Allen' => [
            'name' => 'Allen',
            'age' => (int) 23,
            'marks' => (int) 70
        ],
        'Duke' => [
            'name' => 'Duke',
            'age' => (int) 23,
            'marks' => (int) 67
        ]
    ],
    (int) 24 => [
        'Matt' => [
            'name' => 'Matt',
            'age' => (int) 24,
            'marks' => (int) 85
        ]
    ]
]

\src\Controller\PagesController.php (line 63)

[
    (int) 20 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'age' => (int) 20,
            'marks' => (int) 50
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'name' => 'Ryan',
            'age' => (int) 20,
            'marks' => (int) 57
        ]
    ],
    (int) 23 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'name' => 'Allen',
            'age' => (int) 23,
            'marks' => (int) 70
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'name' => 'Duke',
            'age' => (int) 23,
            'marks' => (int) 67
        ]
    ],
    (int) 24 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'name' => 'Matt',
            'age' => (int) 24,
            'marks' => (int) 85
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, for adding detailed solutions.